# Intercept elasticsearch result from the search endpoint

Tags: elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to create an elasticsearch plugin that does the following:
 1.Intercept the result received from the query sents to localhost:9200/index/type/_search.
2. Manipulate fields in the result hits.
3. Returns the final maniplated data to the client

I looked at the Java API doc at https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/2.4.0. Unfortunately, it's not well explanatory.
I don't know how to move on.
Any guide will be appreciated.

Comment: and what is the motivation behind this approach..instead of storing the modified fields before it hits ES. maybe modify the results in logstash itself?

Comment: My modification involves transforming the score fileld value of each hit. The transformation algorithm depends on data retrieved from another third party service.